# How to extend the size of a specific QPushButton without the others when the widget be maximized

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5

How to extend the object(`QPushButton`) which colored in brown.

[image]

Frankly, I have tried to do that by add `Horizontal layout` but was does not appears fine.

As in the picture, I want to extend(the width only) the size of a specific QPushButton without the others when the widget be maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all these buttons to be inside the horizontal layout. Then you need to play with `QSizePolicy`. For your example you shuold leave the first 3 buttons with `QSizePolicy::Fixed` and set `QSizePolicy::Expanding` to the 4th one.

P.S. Layout should get all the horizontal space your window has. It should not be of a fixed size.

Comment: I gave you the best answer because you gave me the the first seed to arrive to the solution, but your answer not the direct solution. Thank you.